# Create an Excel chart with VBA without manually inputing a range

Tags: excel, charts, range, vba

I have looked around the web for a while and tried different things, not worked. I have a set of data that will vary in length all in different sheet, I wrote a macro to put all of them in one sheet, now they all have different number of rows. I'm trying to put all of them onto a graph but I get stuck when specifying the range. All help would be kindly appreciated, bellow is the code that I manipulated from a recorded Macro:

```
Sub charttest()

    Dim r As Range
    Set r = ActiveSheet.Range("A1").CurrentRegion

    Range("D9").Select
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Select
    ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("'OBA 1'!$A$1" & "r.Columns.Coun, r.Rows.Coun")
    ActiveChart.ChartType = xlXYScatterSmoothNoMarkers
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change the following line:

```
ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("'OBA 1'!$A$1" & "r.Columns.Coun, r.Rows.Coun")
```

into (assuming that `Activesheet` is `OBA 1` sheet:

```
ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=r
```

or into (in other situations):

```
ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("'OBA 1'!" & r.Address)
```

Comment: KazJaw I'm still workin on the program and I face an issue when implementing this into a broader scheme here is my code:

Comment: Next i
                    For i = 1 To 3
    
        Dim g As Range
        Set g = Sheets(i).Range("A1").CurrentRegion
        
               
        Sheets(i).Shapes.AddChart.Select
        Sheets(i).SetSourceData Source:=Range(Sheets(i) & g.Address)
        Sheets(i).SetSourceData Source:=g
        Sheets(i).ChartType = xlXYScatterSmoothNoMarkers

                
    Next i

Comment: Look, you are mixing code structure up. I don't know what is your current problem but what I see: from this `Source:=Range("'OBA 1'!" & r.Address)` you made this `Source:=Range(Sheets(i) & g.Address) ` which is totally different, no `'`, no `!` which are essential. So, try something like `Source:=Range("'" & Sheets(i).Name & "'!" & g.Address)`. One tip- change one thing and test before you change next part of the code. And please, do not put your code here in comments- it's difficult to read. Your problems are new ones so you could as them in different question rather than continuation here.

Comment: but you are in the right place- here in SO. If you have any problems just ask in new questions. Do not repeat them, next accept peoples correct answers and I can promise, there are few good people here to help :)

Answer (score 0):

I reviewed my work and update my code because I wasn't meeting my needs anymore, I ran the code in several pieces and using the method above I end up with an error 13 on my chart function, I'm sure the error comes from the Source line. could any one advise me on the path to follow?

```
Sub t_feuille(f_Work As Worksheet)

Dim num_line As Integer, t_Work As Worksheet
Dim myrange As Range

'instals time column
f_Work.Activate
f_Work.Cells(1, 1) = "Time"
For num_line = 2 To last_line(t_Work)
  f_Work.Cells(num_line, 1) = num_line - 2
Next

'graph set up

  Set myrange = ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion
  Application.CutCopyMode = False
  ActiveChart.ChartWizard _
    Source:=Sheets(f_Work).Range(myrange), _
    Gallery:=xlXYScatterSmoothNoMarkers, Format:=4, PlotBy:=xlColumns, _
    CategoryLabels:=1, SeriesLabels:=1, HasLegend:=1, _
    Title:=f_Work, CategoryTitle:="", _
    ValueTitle:="", ExtraTitle:=""

End Sub

Function last_line(f_Work) As Integer
Dim num_col As Integer, num_line As Integer

  num_line = 0
  For num_col = 1 To ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 10000).End(xlToLeft).Column
    If ActiveSheet.Cells(100000, num_col).End(xlUp).Row > num_line Then
      num_line = ActiveSheet.Cells(100000, num_col).End(xlUp).Row
    End If
Next

  last_line = num_line
End Function
```